# Why does Java Thread.sleep or Date.after() function differently on other computers?

Tags: java, date, sleep

I have a unit test that checks to make sure an object inside my instance is created with a proper Date populated:

```
    Date earlier = new Date();
    Thread.sleep(10);
    instance.execute();
    assertTrue(instance.getMyObject.getCreationDate().after(earlier));
```

This test works for me on Windows 7 Java 6 when running in Eclipse or with Ant from the command line.
However, my client says that this test is failing for him (he didn't specify his environment). How could this be?

Comment: `instance.getMyObject.getCreationDate()` what code replaces this ?

Comment: it's good practice to use the String argument of assertTrue to print some information that would help you to understand why both values are the same/different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Windows XP, the clock resolution is only 1/60 of a second. This means that you can wait 10 ms and the clock time will appear the same.  I would increase the time to 100 to 250 ms.

Answer (score 3):

System.currentTimeMillis has a different "resolution" on different  platforms. 
On Windows it can be 15ms - which would mean that your 10ms wait might not necessarily result in a "later" date.

I would increase the `Thread.sleep(10)` to `Thread.sleep(100)` or more.

Answer (score 1):

As Peter Lawrey has answered, the resolution on the system clock might mean that it hasn't updated between creating your "earlier" date and the instance date.  Perhaps change your code to the following:

```
assertFalse(instance.getMyObject.getCreationDate().before(earlier));
```

This way you are checking that it definitely isn't before your earlier date, and you don't need to worry about whether the system clock has updated or not.